# Google Play Store - web scrape top apps for every genre

Tags: web-scraping, google-play, app-store

Currently when I access the Google Play store from a browser (https://play.google.com/store/apps/top?hl=en), I can only see:

Top Apps, Top Selling Apps, Top Grossing Apps, Top Games, Top Selling Games, Top Grossing games.

I am trying to scrape data to get the top selling/grossing apps on the Play Store for EVERY GENRE of apps (i.e. Education, Health, Social, etc). I would've thought this data would be available on the browser Play Store because apparently it is available on the Android App Play Store. When selecting a category on the web browser Play Store, there are no options to view the top selling/grossing apps.

There are many (commercial) API's that give information on top Google Play apps for each genre so surely this information is able to be scraped from somewhere? For example Applyzer, https://www.applyzer.com/?mmenu=worldcharts shows top apps for every genre on the Play store. I would web scrape from here but I want to do this directly from Google.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

**SOLVED: see my own post below**

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED: I just managed to solve this myself. Turns out the Google Play Store does display this information, but you must manually enter the URL yourself. For example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/BUSINESS/collection/topselling_paid BUSINESS can be replaced by any category, and topselling_paid can be interchanged with topselling_free or topgrossing**

Comment: Thanks for sharing this tip. Did you manage to find other important links not for just 'top-selling-paid' but top downloaded by category?

Comment: Unfortunately, right now your link leads to 404. Working link: [`https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free) or [`https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_paid`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_paid)